# declaring delegates for use as lambdas cast exception

Tags: vb.net, delegates

Does using lambda expressions leed to memory leak?

I'm trying to declare a delegate inside a sub and use it as a "once only" event handler then set it to nothing once it has been fired. somthing like this:

```
Private Sub MySub()
    Dim o As SomeObject
    Dim d as System.Delegate = Sub()
                  'Do some stuff
                   d = Nothing
                End Sub
    AddHandler o.SomeEvent, d
End Sub
```

but I get an invalid cast exception on the addhandler. but is something like this possible/needed?

sry for no code hilite i'm on stack mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example is a windows form; the form contains a single button with its Click event wired to the subroutine: Button1_Click.

Clicking the button causes the SomeClass to be created (o), an event handler is added and the work started. StartWork will call the Anonymous method which creates a thread, using another Anonymous method which simulates work and then releases the (o) reference.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Class SomeClass
        Public Event DoWork()

        Sub StartWork()
            RaiseEvent DoWork()
        End Sub
    End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Debug.WriteLine("Button1_Click Started.")
        ' create class
        Dim o As New SomeClass()
        ' add handlers
        AddHandler o.DoWork, Sub()
                                 Debug.WriteLine("o.DoWork Event Handler Started.")
                                 ' threading
                                 Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                                                   Debug.WriteLine("Worker Thread Started.")
                                                                   ' simulate work (5 seconds)
                                                                   Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
                                                                   ' release reference
                                                                   o = Nothing
                                                                   Debug.WriteLine("Worker Thread Stopped.")
                                                               End Sub)
                                 t.Start()
                                 Debug.WriteLine("o.DoWork Event Handler Stopped.")
                             End Sub
        ' start the work
        o.StartWork()
        Debug.WriteLine("Button1_Click Stopped.")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hmmm... In the time I was waiting for some one to answer, I kind of had the same idea. but then thought about whether just using the built in EventHandler/RoutedEventHandler Class would do the same thing. kind of like o = New EventHandler(SomeLambdaFunction) then, from within the SomeLambdaFunction function, setting o = Nothing. would this also release the object and lambda for GC?